# Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined' in children component

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, undefined

In my expo typescript app, I have a function in a root component:

```
  const getCardType = (type = ECardType.WOOD) => {
    setCardType(type);
  };
```

and pass it in my first child component:

```
  <Slider data={slideData} autoPlay={false} getCardType={getCardType} />
```

Here is my first child component where I pass the function, and it types declaration:

```
  readonly getCardType?: (type: ECardType) => void;



  const Slider: React.FunctionComponent<ISliderProps> = ({
    data,
    autoPlay,
    getCardType,
 })
```

After that I pass it into a second child component:

```
<SliderCardItem cardItem={item} index={index} getCardType={getCardType} />
```

And in this **SliderItem** component, I use this function:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getCardType(cardType);
  }, [cardType]);
```

But Have a TS error:  **Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined' in children component**

I set the **cardType** below in an **onPress()**
I have this error only in this component
An idea to fix this error?

Comment: As an aside... A function called `getCardType` which internally calls a function called `setCardType` sounds like you're setting yourself up for confusing bugs later on.  It's not actually *getting* a value, it's *setting* a value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getCardType` might be undefined, as stated in your type here:

`getCardType?: (type: ECardType) => void;`

Then you're trying to call it without checking if it exists:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getCardType(cardType);
}, [cardType]);
```

So you'll need to perform that check:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (getCardType) getCardType(cardType);
}, [cardType]);
```

or with optional chaining:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getCardType?.(cardType);
}, [cardType]);
```

If it will always be present then you can make it non optional in your type:

`getCardType: (type: ECardType) => void;`

Comment: Thx by checking if it exists with the optional chaining, it works ;)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `?` in the type declaration, if it's required. If it's not required, you have to check if it exists first.

Another point, `getCardType` is actually a dependency of that effect as well, but by looking at it it's safe, to ignore it (because it just wraps a setState) call.

I don't like ignoring stuff, though. So if I were you, I'd probably write it like this:

```
  // useCallback makes getCardType referentially identical between renders
  const getCardType = useCallback((type = ECardType.WOOD) => {
    setCardType(type);

  // safe to ignore setCardType in the dependencies because it's a dispatcher
  },[]);

// ... and in the child:

  useEffect(() => {
    getCardType(cardType);
  }, [ getCardType, cardType ]);
```

I'm honestly dying to know what that `useEffect` is about in the child, because it smells a little fishy.